# How to retain a blank album title in RhythmBox

Tags: music, rhythmbox, notification

When I set the album title of a song to be blank in RhythmBox then when I play the song the notification will show it as '`Song title` by `Artist`' which is what I want.  But every time I close and reopen RhythmBox it sets all blank album titles to what they previously were, in this case `Unknown`, so the notifications read '`Song title` by `Artist` from `Unknown`' which looks gross. Is there a way to keep the album title blank without it resetting it to `Unknown`?

Edit: RhythmBox is version 3.0.2 running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Edit your question with your `Rhythmbox` version. Found at *Help* > *About*

Comment: it has been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say you can't change that, **it is a bug**, and as you can see it's been reported several times since several past versions of `Rhythmbox`.

Reported at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/58941), [Bugzilla 1](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=556828), [Bugzilla 2](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=328971) and [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=680584).

You can go to any of those sites to mark the bug affects you as well, and wait a response regarding any future patch solving it.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @ChristianF97 You are asking how to do *X*, I'm telling you that you can't do *X* because of a bug. Despite that, your question should be closed as its a bug that should be reported, therefore, off-topic. Flagged it because of that but as there's a bounty it cant be closed.

Comment: My apologies, I misread a couple things

Comment: Your answer was the most helpful for me, therefore you have been awarded the bounty.

Comment: @ChristianF97 No problem, I'm sorry this wasn't the kind of answer expected

Answer (score 1):

`Rhythmbox` plays songs using a **reference to the file** , and it does store some information about the ID3 tags but that may not be your case for the album section.

What you can do is edit those tags directly on the song files. There are different options to do that, here you have some that run *natively on linux* and support `mp3`,`mp4`, `FLAC` and others:

- [EasyTAG](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG)  allows a lot of editing options.
- `mid3v2` for the command line. You can get it with `sudo apt-get install python-pip;sudo pip install mutagen`
- [Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) cross-platform .

---

As requested, **how to use `mid3v2`**:

> **DESCRIPTION** - *from mutagen*
>
> mid3v2 is a Mutagen-based replacement for id3lib’s id3v2. It supports >ID3v2.4 and more frames; it also does not have the numerous bugs that plague >id3v2.
>
> This program exists mostly for compatibility with programs that want to tag >files using id3v2. For a more usable interface, we recommend [Ex Falso](http://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/commands/exfalso.html).
>
> - **General syntax**
>
> `mid3v2 [options] filename ...`
>
> In order to change album name use this option:
>
> `--album=ALBUM_NAME`
>
> **Example**: Go to the directory where the file is located and run
>
> `mid3v2 --album=Ubuntu Foosong.mp3`
>
> This will set the album of the song 'Foosong' to be 'Ubuntu'.

Source and more info for `mid3v2` [here](http://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/mid3v2.html)

---

If even after setting the `Album` tag blank, `Unknown` appears on `Rhythmbox`, you can try to name the `Album` tag with an *Arabian* character, wich shouldnt be recognized and show a blank space instead. Get wichever you like the most from [here](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%88).

Comment: Please make this answer more extensive - explain how to use the mid3v2 command

Comment: @ChristianF97 Edited it! Hope it can help you better now.

Comment: I've tried all those methods and they all do the same thing RhythmBox does - I can use them to make a blank album title but when RhythmBox reloads it sets them all back to unknown.  Contrary to what you said, Arabian characters do show up, and even if they didn't the notification would say '`Song title` by `Artist` from' which is almost more infuriating than saying 'from Unknown'